# c# : how create a class extends ByteArray in c#

Tags: c#

i am doing a conversion from JAVA to c#

in my java i have this class

```
public class Axe extends ByteArray {

}
```

By right i think should be in this way ,

```
public class Axe : ByteArray {

}
```

but the problem is in c# it does not have the ByteArray for me to extend

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain how you wish to extend the class. Adding this context will help us give you better answers.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you need? It is not clear from your post. A ByteArray is a byte[] in C#. You cannot extend this, but you can write Extension Methods for it in .NET3+: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should just write some extension methods for `byte[]`:

```
static class ByteExtensions
{
    public static string DoSomething(this byte[] x)
    {
        return "Length of this byte array: " + x.Length;
    }
}

// ...

void Foo()
{
    var b = new byte[5];
    b.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[ByteArray](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ByteArraywrapsjavabytearraysbytetoallowbytearraystobeusedaskeysinhashtables.htm) is a wrapper Class in java  which wrappes byte[]( a array of bytes) and provides methods to maipulate. if required you could write your own wrapper class in C#,

Link provides Sample Wrapper Class for [ByteArray](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ByteArraywrapsjavabytearraysbytetoallowbytearraystobeusedaskeysinhashtables.htm) in java.

hopes that helps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend a byte array, but if you want to use your class like an array, you can provide Indexers:

```
public class Axe {

    private byte[] data = new byte[whateverLength];

    public byte this[int index] {
        get { return data[index]; }
        set { data[index] = value; }
    }

}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
Axe myAxe = new Axe();
myAxe[someIndex] = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a: Byte[]?

Answer (score 0):

if you absolutely want to implement your own byte-typed collection implement one of the interfaces like [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx):

```
public class Axe : IList<Byte>
```

or if you just need bits and not bytes consider using the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)

Comment: You can't subclass `Array`/arrays like that. (And although you can subclass `List<T>` it's not usually very useful because `List<T>` has no virtual members that you can override.)